# Specify dimensions for canvas element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

See below code. How do I specify a width and height within these lines?

Specifying a width and height using css does not work.

```
wrapper.append(
            $('<canvas />', { class: 'canvasClass', id: 'cElement' })
        );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since canvas accepts `width` and `height` attribute

Try to use,

```
wrapper.append(
  $('<canvas />', { class: 'canvasClass', id: 'cElement' ,width:200, height:200 })
);
```

Comment: This works. Is it isn't possible to specify a '%' like in css?

Comment: @Fergoso we really don't need to specify that, since it would automatically consider that as a pixel while rendering. And if you want to set it based on a percentage, you should mention the percentage as a mandatory thing.

Comment: That's correct. So it'll be always 'px' but can not specify a '%' within this line.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use below code:

```
$('.canvasClass').width(500).height(300);
```